# Settings prerender.io for meteor.js on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, web-crawler, prerender

1) I have installed and ran the application `meteor.js` https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react

2) I have installed `prerender` server near to the application directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git
cd prerender
npm install
```

and set port:

```
export PORT=3050
```

end run

```
node server.js
```

3) I have installed module `prerender-node`:

```
meteor npm install prerender-node --save
```

Set the environment variables:

```
export PRERENDER_SERVICE_URL="http://localhost:3050/"
```

4) And I wrote in `./server/main.js`:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import prerenderIO from 'prerender-node';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  prerenderIO.set('host', 'localhost');
  prerenderIO.set('protocol', 'http');
  prerenderIO.set('port', '3000');
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(prerenderIO);
});
```

But when I go to the link `view-source:http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=` I do not see the rendered `html`.

I see an error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_= 504
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any console output on your prerender server logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earned configuration option:

```
    import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import prerenderio from 'prerender-node';

    Meteor.startup(() => {
      prerenderio.set('host', 'localhost:3000');
      prerenderio.set('protocol', 'http');
      prerenderio.set('forwardHeaders', true);
      prerenderio.set('afterRender', function afterRender(error) {
          if (error) {
             console.log('prerenderio error', error);
             return;
          }
     });
     WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(prerenderio); 
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import prerenderio from 'prerender-node';
Meteor.startup(() => {
const settings = Meteor.settings.PrerenderIO;
if (settings && settings.token && settings.protocol) {
    prerenderio.set('prerenderToken', settings.token);
    prerenderio.set('protocol', settings.protocol);
    prerenderio.set('forwardHeaders', true);
    prerenderio.set('afterRender', function afterRender(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('prerenderio error', error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
            return;
        }
    });
    WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(prerenderio);
}
});
```

settings.json

```
{
 "PrerenderIO": {
    "token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "protocol": "http" //https
},
}
```

Comment: I do not need a token from http://prerender.io as I unfold the server locally and where to get a token for the local server?